# making a installer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I have been working on this, very, small photo cms lately. And now i ready for setting it up to Github. So i will love to have some kind of installer, just as much for leaning it, I'm thinking something like you type a command and then it starts by copy all the files to the rails app, and then asking you for what your flickr_id is etc..

So i have to store all this information  and call it down.. i.e if i should show some pictures, i have to use the flickr_id.

Hope you understood my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by using [rails-app-installer](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-app-installer), it's not maintain completly but can works. It's use on the [Typo project](http://github.com/fdv/typo)